# Iterate and print the content of all files in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to the Ruby world so please bear if its a simple query.

For one of my assignments, I'm looking to read the contents of all the text files in a folder (only top level) and redirect the file contents to a single output file in a appended or merged manner.

I'm a expecting a format like below:

**Output File**

```
File Name: 1st file name

all its contents
====================================
File Name: 2nd file name

all its contents
====================================
File Name: 3rd file name

all its contents
====================================
   ....
   ....


====================================
```

I managed to write the below script but the output file is empty. Any suggestions please.

```
File.open('C:\Users\darkop\Desktop\final_output.txt','a') do |final|
  @files = Dir.glob("D:\text\*.txt")
  for file in @files
    text = File.open(file, 'r').read.sub(/#$/?\z/, $/)
    text.each_line do |line|
      puts "File Name:"#{file}
      puts
      final << line
      puts "=" * 20 
      end
  end
end
```

Also, is it possible to redirect the output in aforementioned format to a word document instead of a text file ?

Many thanks.

Comment: You have included the "attempt" and "expected output" in your question. You should also add "your output" or "error" you are getting.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh : I'm getting empty/blank output file . Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

The file name was empty because you have `puts "File Name:"#{file}`. This way `#{file}` doesn't get interpolated, because it isn't inside the double quotation marks.

Also, you didn't get the contents of the file because you just used `puts`, instead of `puts line`, which is what you want.

```
File.open('C:\Users\darkop\Desktop\final_output.txt','a') do |final|
  @files = Dir.glob("D:\text\*.txt")
  for file in @files
    text = File.open(file, 'r').read.sub(/#$/?\z/, $/)
    text.each_line do |line|
      puts "File Name: #{file}"
      puts
      puts line
      final << line
      puts "=" * 20 
    end
  end
end
```

-EDIT-

Since you are new to Ruby, it's better to use an `each` loop, instead of the `for .. in` loop. Also, just specify the output name with a `.doc` extension for a Word document.

```
File.open('C:\Users\darkop\Desktop\final_output.doc','a') do |final|
  @files = Dir.glob("D:\text\*.txt")
  @files.each do |file|
    text = File.open(file, 'r').read.sub(/#$/?\z/, $/)
    text.each_line do |line|
      puts "File Name: #{file}"
      puts
      puts line
      final << line
      puts "=" * 20 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Van Dijik : +1 for identifying my mistake.

I made further modifications to get the above format:

`File.open('D:/output.doc','a') do |final|
  @files = Dir.glob("D:/text/*.txt")
  for file in @files
    final.puts "File Name: #{file}"
 final.puts
    text = File.open(file, 'r').read.sub(/#$/?\z/, $/)
    text.each_line do |line|
      final << line
  end
 final.puts "=" * 70 
  end
end`

Appreciate your time here.